# Azure Virtual Machine Microphone and Speaker

Tags: azure, audio, virtual-machine, playsound

How we can enable the microphone on the Azure virtual machine while keep hearing the sound of the system as well?? When I change the RDP setting to "play on this computer", I can hear the sound of system but not able to use a microphone and when I select the "play on remote computer" I can use the microphone but can't hear sound. Is it any way to work both things simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you enable both audio and mic..
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fbe0e7fa-f47d-46cd-b74b-2fa90aa05efd/enabling-audio-on-azure-vm?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows

Comment: Not sure then, sorry.